# Post-hoc tukey test after repeated measures ANOVA in R taking into account spherecity

Tags: r, repeated-measures, tukey-hsd-test, sphericity

I am trying to do some repeated measure anova in `R`.

Consider the following data.

```
uni <- read.table("http://www.stat.ufl.edu/~winner/data/phsynco2u.dat",
                  header=F,col.names=c("pop","trt.ph","id","co2conc","co2uptake"))

multi <- read.table("http://www.stat.ufl.edu/~winner/data/phsynco2m.dat",
                    header=F,col.names=c("pop","trt.ph","id","y95","y175","y250","y350","y500",
                                         "y675","y1000"))
```

Here `co2uptake` is the dependent variable, `pop` and `trt.ph` are the between-subjects variable and `co2conc` is the within subject variable. So there are both between and within subject independent variables.

I am trying to follow the multivariate approach in http://www.gribblelab.org/stats/notes/RepeatedMeasuresANOVA.html

```
concLevels <- c(95,175,250,350,500,675,1000)
concFactor <- as.factor(concLevels)
concFrame <- data.frame(concFactor)
concModel <- lm(cbind(y95,y175,y250,y350,y500,y675,y1000) ~ pop*trt.ph, data = multi)

library(car)
mod <- Anova(concModel, idata=concFrame, idesign = ~concFactor, type = "III")
summary(mod)

Univariate Type III Repeated-Measures ANOVA Assuming Sphericity

                           SS num Df Error SS den Df       F    Pr(>F)    
(Intercept)           1463.34      1   282.83      8 41.3911 0.0002018 ***
pop                     16.75      1   282.83      8  0.4736 0.5107747    
trt.ph                  18.60      1   282.83      8  0.5261 0.4889052    
pop:trt.ph             225.73      1   282.83      8  6.3849 0.0354301 *  
concFactor              58.48      6   188.63     48  2.4802 0.0359770 *  
pop:concFactor          26.82      6   188.63     48  1.1377 0.3552599    
trt.ph:concFactor       56.26      6   188.63     48  2.3862 0.0425070 *  
pop:trt.ph:concFactor  111.96      6   188.63     48  4.7484 0.0007171 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1


Mauchly Tests for Sphericity

                      Test statistic  p-value
concFactor                 0.0019393 0.027075
pop:concFactor             0.0019393 0.027075
trt.ph:concFactor          0.0019393 0.027075
pop:trt.ph:concFactor      0.0019393 0.027075


Greenhouse-Geisser and Huynh-Feldt Corrections
 for Departure from Sphericity

                       GG eps Pr(>F[GG])  
concFactor            0.48934    0.08704 .
pop:concFactor        0.48934    0.35354  
trt.ph:concFactor     0.48934    0.09575 .
pop:trt.ph:concFactor 0.48934    0.01031 *
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

                         HF eps  Pr(>F[HF])
concFactor            0.8038704 0.050169682
pop:concFactor        0.8038704 0.356639187
trt.ph:concFactor     0.8038704 0.057703998
pop:trt.ph:concFactor 0.8038704 0.001967902
```

Based on Mauchly's test, the spherecity assumption is invalidated.

According to http://www.gribblelab.org/stats/notes/RepeatedMeasuresANOVA.html, in case of spherecity, the tukey test can be done as follows:
(I have used the  custom function [`pairwise.t.test.with.t.and.df`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35760246/3223138) to scale the t-tests.

```
# Tukey test for within-subject variable (co2conc)
#--------------------------------------------------
ttest <- pairwise.t.test.with.t.and.df(uni$co2uptake, uni$co2conc, pool.sd = F)

# When dfnum=1, F=t^2
F.value <- ttest$t.value^2

# Compute q stat
qobs <- sqrt(2*F.value)

# compute tukey p value
# df for q are (a,(a-1)(n-1))
table(uni$co2conc, uni$id)

       1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12
  95   1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1  1  1  1
  175  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1  1  1  1
  250  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1  1  1  1
  350  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1  1  1  1
  500  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1  1  1  1
  675  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1  1  1  1
  1000 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1  1  1  1

n <- ncol(table(uni$co2conc, uni$id)) # num subjects per group 
a <- nrow(table(uni$co2conc, uni$id)) # num groups

pt <- 1 - ptukey(qobs, a, (a-1)*(n-1))

pt > 0.05

        95   175  250  350  500  675
175  FALSE    NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
250  FALSE  TRUE   NA   NA   NA   NA
350  FALSE  TRUE TRUE   NA   NA   NA
500  FALSE  TRUE TRUE TRUE   NA   NA
675  FALSE  TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE   NA
1000 FALSE FALSE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
```

**Question 1**: Is my approach for post-hoc test after multivariate test correct ?

**Question 2**: If yes, how to compute the post-hoc tests for the interactions (`pop` $\times$ `concFactor`, `trt.ph` $\times$  `concFactor`, `pop` $\times$  `trt.ph` $\times$  `concFactor`)?